# ColdFusion 11 Running on IIS Server and getting a Java CreateObject Error

Tags: java, coldfusion

I am getting the error below when trying to create an object in ColdFusion 11 using `cfscript`. In the ColdFusion Admin Java VM settings are the default setting. I have placed `xmlsec-1.5.8.jar` file under `\cfusion\lib` and `cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\lib`. I have also restarted the ColdFusion service.

```
obj = CreateObject("Java","org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature");
```

**Error:**

```
Could not initialize class org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature null 
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature** 
at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43) 
at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:142)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1082) 
at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1063) 
at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:387) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) 
at coldfusion.runtime.StructBean.invoke(StructBean.java:508) 
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2553) 
at cfdump2ecfm2106091068$funcDUMPOBJECT.runFunction(/WEB-INF/cftags/dump.cfm:1797)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487) 
at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47) 
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383) 
at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334) 
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:533) 
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2805) 
at cfdump2ecfm2106091068$funcRENDEROUTPUT.runFunction(/WEB-INF/cftags/dump.cfm:681)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487) 
at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47) 
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383) 
at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334) 
at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:231) 
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2840) 
at cfdump2ecfm2106091068._factor17(/WEB-INF/cftags/dump.cfm:565) 
at cfdump2ecfm2106091068._factor25(/WEB-INF/cftags/dump.cfm:564) 
at cfdump2ecfm2106091068._factor3(/WEB-INF/cftags/dump.cfm) 
at cfdump2ecfm2106091068._factor54(/WEB-INF/cftags/dump.cfm:493) 
at cfdump2ecfm2106091068.runPage(/WEB-INF/cftags/dump.cfm:1) 
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:246) 
at coldfusion.filter.CFVariablesScopeFilter.invoke(CFVariablesScopeFilter.java:56)
at coldfusion.tagext.lang.ModuleTag.doStartTag(ModuleTag.java:332) 
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2986) 
at cfjavatest2ecfm1994854383.runPage(J:\PPNPF_WEB\SAMLTEST\javatest.cfm:8)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:246) 
at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:736)
at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:572)
at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
at coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:45) 
at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:487) 
at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:42)
at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:142) 
at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94) 
at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38) 
at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58) 
at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) 
at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) 
at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62) 
at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219) 
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) 
at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42) 
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) 
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) 
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:422)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:199) 
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: However, when i  do the following and do a writedump(obj), I get no error.  obj  = CreateObject("Java", "org.apache.xml.security.utils.Constants").SignatureSpecNS;

Comment: *I have placed xmlsec-1.5.8.jar file under...* No. Do not place the same jar file in multiple locations on the CF class path. Pick one only. The multiple versions might be causing the problem. Check the logs. Is there a "caused by" section listed at the bottom of the trace?

Comment: As soon as I remove it from one location, it started to work. I appreciate you help. Why is it causing a problem when the file is identical in both places?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the "caused by" section of the trace.  *when the file is identical in both places* When working with class loaders, it is .. a little more complicated. Suffice it to say you need to follow certain rules. There should only be one version of a library in the class path. Otherwise, you can run into errors like this one or get stuck in [jar hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader#JAR_hell). That said, there are a number of possible causes of NoClassDefFoundError. We need to see more of the trace to pinpoint the exact cause in this case.